# Threading the right choice?

Tags: multithreading, delphi

Im new to threads, therefore im not sure if threads are the right way to approach this.

My program needs to perform a calculation a couple of times, same logik behind it, but with different parameters. The longer the calculation, the closer it will be to the perfect answer. The calculation duration cant be measured beforehanded (from a few seconds to a couple of minutes)

The user wants to have the results in an order (from calculation 1 to X) at certain times. He is satisfied with not the perfect solution as long as it he gets a result. Once he has a solution, he is not interested in the one before (example: he has a not perfect answer from calculation 1 and demands now answer from calculation 2; even if there is a better answer now for calculation 1, he is not interested in it)

Is threading the right way to do this?

Comment: It depends on things you haven't stated. Does the calculation take 1 millisecond or 1 second or 100 seconds?  For you to get a benefit in the multi-threading department, your returns on effort are vanishingly small, if your calculation only takes 10 milliseconds to run.

Comment: Even if it's a long calculation, the only real reason to do this inside of a thread is 1) if there are multiple different calculations to be done at the same time as each other, or 2) if you want the UI to remain responsive during the time of this calculation.

Comment: @JerryDodge I think we're safely at the point in this day and age that any lengthy processing should as a matter of course be done asynchronously.  If you don't service the message queue for something like a handful of seconds Windows Vista and up will fade the window, tell the user the application is not responding, and will offer to have them kill the process.  That really leaves three viable options : (1) `Application.ProcessMessages`, which we can happily leave by the wayside; (2) Background thread, or (3) Homebrew `PeekMessage`/`Dispatch` loop...which should probably be used with caution.

Comment: @J... You mention to use caution with this, yet you should use EXTREME caution when using `Application.ProcessMessages` - better yet, don't consider using it at all.

Comment: @JerryDodge Well, that's what I meant with the "leaving by the wayside" - perhaps the expression is not so widely known.  It means to leave a thing behind - to let fall into disuse, etc.

Comment: @ WarrenP Its written in what time range the calculation varies
@ JerryDodge I wanted both, the calculation has the same logic behind, but different input and be able to grab results when they are available without the need to let the calculation finish completly
@ J... I agree with not using PrecessMessages for this, I wouldnt toss it away completly, but in almost all cases there are better solutions, like the Thread for my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Threading sounds like a good approach for this, as you can perform your long-running computation on a background thread while keeping your UI responsive.

In order to satisfy your requirement of having results in an order, you may need a way of stopping threads that are no longer needed. Either abort them (may be extreme), or just signal them to stop and/or return the current result.

Note you may want the threads to periodically check back in with the UI to report progress (% complete), check for any abort requests, etc. Although this depends entirely upon your application and is not necessarily required.

Comment: Threading it worked like a charm, its not possible to give a feedback back (the recursion itself doesnt know when its done), but a count of the possible solutions were all I need. Thx